# Динамический прокси

Tags: java

Вот мой код:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Proxy.*;
import java.util.Set;
import java.lang.reflect.*;
import java.util.*;

interface PersonBean {

    String getName();
    String getGender();
    String getInterests();
    int getHotOrNotRating();

    void setName(String name);
    void setGender(String gender);
    void setInterests(String interests);
    void setHotOrNotRating(int rating); 
}

class OwnerInvocationHandler implements InvocationHandler { 
    PersonBean person;

    public OwnerInvocationHandler(PersonBean person) {
        this.person = person;
    }

    public Object invoke(Object proxy, Method method, Object[] args) 
            throws IllegalAccessException {

        try {
            if (method.getName().startsWith("get")) {
                return method.invoke(person, args);
               } else if (method.getName().equals("setHotOrNotRating")) {
                throw new IllegalAccessException();
            } else if (method.getName().startsWith("set")) {
                return method.invoke(person, args);
            } 
        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        return null;
    }
}

class NonOwnerInvocationHandler implements InvocationHandler { 
    PersonBean person;

    public NonOwnerInvocationHandler(PersonBean person) {
        this.person = person;
    }

    public Object invoke(Object proxy, Method method, Object[] args) 
            throws IllegalAccessException {

        try {
            if (method.getName().startsWith("get")) {
                return method.invoke(person, args);
               } else if (method.getName().equals("setHotOrNotRating")) {
                return method.invoke(person, args);
            } else if (method.getName().startsWith("set")) {
                throw new IllegalAccessException();
            } 
        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        return null;
    }
}

class PersonBeanImpl implements PersonBean {
    String name;
    String gender; 
    String interests;
    int rating;
    int ratingCount = 0;

    public String getName() {
        return name;    
    } 

    public String getGender() {
        return gender;
    }

    public String getInterests() {
        return interests;
    }

    public int getHotOrNotRating() { 
        if (ratingCount == 0) return 0;
        return (rating/ratingCount);
    }


    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setGender(String gender) {
        this.gender = gender;
    } 

    public void setInterests(String interests) {
        this.interests = interests;
    } 

    public void setHotOrNotRating(int rating) {
        ratingCount++;
    }
}

public class MatchMakingTestDrive {
    public Hashtable <String, PersonBean> datingDB = new Hashtable <String, PersonBean> ();
     String Name;
    String gender;
    String Interests;
    int HotOrNotRating;
public static void main(String[] args) {
        MatchMakingTestDrive test = new MatchMakingTestDrive();
        test.drive();
    }

    public void drive() {
        PersonBean joe = getPersonFromDatabase("Joe Javabean");  
        PersonBean ownerProxy = getOwnerProxy(joe);
        System.out.println("Name is " + ownerProxy.getName());
        ownerProxy.setInterests("bowling, Go");
        System.out.println("Interests set from owner proxy");
        try {
            ownerProxy.setHotOrNotRating(10);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Can't set rating from owner proxy");
        }
        System.out.println("Rating is " + ownerProxy.getHotOrNotRating());

       PersonBean nonOwnerProxy = getNonOwnerProxy(joe);
        System.out.println("Name is " + nonOwnerProxy.getName());
        try {
            nonOwnerProxy.setInterests("bowling, Go");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Can't set interests from non owner proxy");
        }
        nonOwnerProxy.setHotOrNotRating(3);
        System.out.println("Rating set from non owner proxy");
        System.out.println("Rating is " + nonOwnerProxy.getHotOrNotRating());
    }

    PersonBean getOwnerProxy(PersonBean person) {

        return (PersonBean) java.lang.reflect.Proxy.newProxyInstance( 
                person.getClass().getClassLoader(),
                person.getClass().getInterfaces(),
               new OwnerInvocationHandler(person)); 
    }

    PersonBean getNonOwnerProxy(PersonBean person) {

       return (PersonBean)java.lang.reflect. Proxy.newProxyInstance(
          person.getClass().getClassLoader(),
           person.getClass().getInterfaces(),
         new NonOwnerInvocationHandler(person));
    }

    PersonBean getPersonFromDatabase(String name) {
        return datingDB.get(name);
    }

    void initializeDatabase() {
        PersonBean joe = new PersonBeanImpl();
        joe.setName("Joe Javabean");
        joe.setInterests("cars, computers, music");
        joe.setHotOrNotRating(7);
        datingDB.put(joe.getName(), joe);

        PersonBean kelly = new PersonBeanImpl();
        kelly.setName("Kelly Klosure");
        kelly.setInterests("ebay, movies, music");
        kelly.setHotOrNotRating(6);
        datingDB.put(kelly.getName(), kelly);
    }
 }
```

После запуска программы мне выдает это:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at MatchMakingTestDrive.getOwnerProxy(MatchMakingTestDrive.java:150)
        at MatchMakingTestDrive.drive(MatchMakingTestDrive.java:125)
        at MatchMakingTestDrive.main(MatchMakingTestDrive.java:119)
```

Comment: Покажите строку 150 из файла `MatchMakingTestDrive.java`.

Comment: 150        return (PersonBean) java.lang.reflect.Proxy.newProxyInstance( 
                person.getClass().getClassLoader(),
                person.getClass().getInterfaces(),
               new OwnerInvocationHandler(person)); 
    }

Comment: Кстати, welcome to Stack Overflow! =)

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 4):

Кажется, вы забыли проинициализировать (заполнить записями) `datingDB`. Добавьте строчку, помеченную восклицательными знаками, в метод main:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    MatchMakingTestDrive test = new MatchMakingTestDrive();
    test.initialize();  // !!
    test.drive();
}
```

`getPersonFromDatabase()` возвращает null, т.к. пользователь `"Joe Javabean"` не найден в БД. Тогда на строке `person.getClass().getClassLoader()` конечно же возникнет [NPE](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/NullPointerException.html).

Comment: @Natka если ответ вам помог и вы считаете его правильным, не забудьте отметить его зелёной галочкой. это будет означать, что вопрос закрыт. Начните с этой страницы, чтобы быстро ознакомиться с сайтом: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour